# indexOf and lastIndexOf in PHP?

Tags: php, indexof, lastindexof

In Java, we can use `indexOf` and `lastIndexOf`. Since those functions don't exist in PHP, what would be the PHP equivalent of this Java code?

```
if(req_type.equals("RMT"))
    pt_password = message.substring(message.indexOf("-")+1);
else 
    pt_password = message.substring(message.indexOf("-")+1,message.lastIndexOf("-"));
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php

Comment: you can use the IndexOf and LastIndexOf by using JavaScript because they exists in it.

Comment: *"Since those functions don't exist in PHP"* -- have you searched them? Last time I checked, PHP was still providing this functionality. `indexOf` is named [`strpos()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php), `lastIndexOf` is named [`strrpos()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php).

Answer (score 64):

You need the following functions to do this in PHP:

> [`strpos`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) Find the position of the first occurrence of a substring in a string
>
> [`strrpos`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php) Find the position of the last occurrence of a substring in a string
>
> [`substr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) Return part of a string

Here's the signature of the `substr` function:

```
string substr ( string $string , int $start [, int $length ] )
```

The signature of the `substring` function (Java) looks a bit different:

```
string substring( int beginIndex, int endIndex )
```

`substring` (Java) expects the end-index as the last parameter, but `substr` (PHP) expects a length.

It's not hard, to [get the desired length by the end-index in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7033178/2123108):

```
$sub = substr($str, $start, $end - $start);
```

Here is the working code

```
$start = strpos($message, '-') + 1;
if ($req_type === 'RMT') {
    $pt_password = substr($message, $start);
}
else {
    $end = strrpos($message, '-');
    $pt_password = substr($message, $start, $end - $start);
}
```

Answer (score 22):

In php:

- [**stripos()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php) function is used to find the position of the first occurrence of a case-insensitive substring in a string.
- [**strripos()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strripos.php) function is used to find the position of the last occurrence of a case-insensitive substring in a string.

> Sample code:

```
$string = 'This is a string';
$substring ='i';
$firstIndex = stripos($string, $substring);
$lastIndex = strripos($string, $substring);

echo 'Fist index = ' . $firstIndex . ' ' . 'Last index = '. $lastIndex;
```

> Output: Fist index = 2 Last index = 13

Answer (score 5):

```php
<?php
// sample array
$fruits3 = [
    "iron",
    1,
    "ascorbic",
    "potassium",
    "ascorbic",
    2,
    "2",
    "1",
];

// Let's say we are looking for the item "ascorbic", in the above array

//a PHP function matching indexOf() from JS
echo(array_search("ascorbic", $fruits3, true)); //returns "2"

// a PHP function matching lastIndexOf() from JS world
function lastIndexOf($needle, $arr)
{
    return array_search($needle, array_reverse($arr, true), true);
}

echo(lastIndexOf("ascorbic", $fruits3)); //returns "4"

// so these (above) are the two ways to run a function similar to indexOf and lastIndexOf()
```

Answer (score -2):

This is the best way to do it, very simple.

```
$msg = "Hello this is a string";
$first_index_of_i = stripos($msg,'i');
$last_index_of_i = strripos($msg, 'i');

echo "First i : " . $first_index_of_i . PHP_EOL ."Last i : " . $last_index_of_i;
```

Comment: Please put your answer always in context instead of just pasting code. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for more details.

Comment: What makes it "the best" exactly?