# Extract string between first whitespace and last whitespace in php

Tags: php

I have this string i want to extract string which is between first occurence of whitespace and last occurence of white space

```
$string="...ence it is apparent why many are in the favour of the above stance. Another argument i...";
```

i want to extract this part `it is apparent why many are in the favour of the above stance. Another argument`

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do this, here is one:

```
<?php
$str_arr = explode(" ", "Your long sentence here.");
$sub_arr = array_slice($str_arr, 1, count($str_arr)-2);
$extracted_str = implode(' ', $sub_arr);
echo $extracted_str; // long sentence
```

Comment: will it affect the sequence or special characters like comma or full stop position when i rebuild the string with implode

Comment: @user3653474 it should be fine, test it before production anyway.

Comment: Sure i will check, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```php
$firstIndex = strpos($string, ' ') + 1;
$lastIndex = strrpos($string, ' ');
substring($string, $firstIndex, $lastIndex - $firstIndex);
```

Reference: [indexOf and lastIndexOf in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26923257/indexof-and-lastindexof-in-php)